# How do you read text from a JTextArea one line at a time?

Tags: java, swing, java-stream, awt, jtextarea

How do you read text from a `JTextArea` one line at a time?

I can only find the `JTextArea.getText(<no parameters>)` function in the docs, but nothing about reading based on line number.  I can get the indices of the start and the end of a given line, and the total number of lines, but I don't know how to extract the data one line at a time.

Comment: If the text is in a JTextArea then it is already in memory. What do you mean by 'hissy fit'?

Comment: Tell us about this data and how you need to process it; maybe we can help you make sense of the `Stream` and `BufferedReader` docs.  Meanwhile, you might want to try [this section of the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) for a quick introduction to streams.

Comment: Besides the tutorial linked by Kevin Anderson, there’s [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) with a more general overview (whereas the class documentation is more specific). Generally, I don’t understand your issue with the documentation. If you prefer short and sloppy, the internet is full of alternatives.

Comment: *so if I could handle it line-by-line then I'd be golden,* - so you read the data line by line. I'm not understanding the problem. *combined with a BufferedReader* - all you need is a FileReader combined with e BufferedReader and then you use the readLine(...) method. Search the site using those keywords to find examples. Or read your text book. File I/O is a topic covered in any text book or basic tutorial. I would suggest you first learn basic I/O before worrying about streams which are far more complex.

Comment: @camickr I can't read it line-by-line, that's the problem.  The only output of a JTextArea is with `JTextArea.getText()`, which returns a single String.  Problem is, the output has too many characters for one string, which means that however the JTextArea is handling the text, it isn't with a single string.  I can get the start/end indices of the line with `JTextArea.getLineStart()` and `End()`, and I can get the number of lines with `.getLineCount()` but I can't actually output one line at a time from the JTextArea with its native functions.

Comment: And this isn't a file, this is a JTextArea.  Did you not read the question, or can you actually use a FileReader to scan a JTextArea?  I didn't see anything like that in the FileReader docs.  I could use a file for my specific case if I absolutely *had* to, but the answer to this is something I'd like to know regardless for other situations.

Comment: There [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254167/#comment117134276_66254167) is the fundamental problem that the content of a `JTextArea` *is already in memory*, so “*read text from a `JTextArea` without loading the string into memory*” makes no sense at all. “3 MB of raw text” isn’t an impressive amount either (we have the year 2021). A `String` can have a billion characters without problems, so “*the output has too many characters for one string*” seems to be a premature assumption. Or post the code to reproduce the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not understanding the question.

Why would you read an entire file into a JTextArea and then read the text in the text area and parse the data?

The point of my answer was that you:

1. Read the CSV file line by line
2. You then parse each line to get the 3 columns of data you need
3. If you really need the entire data in the text file, then you just use the `append(...)` method of the JTextArea to add each line of data as you read it.

> The only output of a JTextArea is with JTextArea.getText()

If you really want to get the data from the text area then read the JTextArea API. The following methods will help you out:

1. `getText(...)` method where you specify the "offset" and "length" parameters, so you can get a line of text
2. `getLines()` for the number of lines of text in the text area
3. `getLineStartOffset(...)` and `getLineEndOffset(...)`

So now you can create a loop and get the text for each individual line.

Comment: So two things: first, it doesn't really matter why, does it?  This isn't code review.  I just want to know how to get this out without blowing up the memory.  Oh but second is I freaking hate the Java docs sometimes because the `getText(int offset, int length)` is SO far away from the `getText()` method that I solely thought existed.  Thanks for letting me know I missed that!

Comment: *it doesn't really matter why, does it?* - yes it does because when you ask a basic question, we don't know if the issue is your lack of understanding of Swing and therefore your approach is completely wrong. We don't want to promote poor design when there are options. *... is SO far away from...* - tip -  if you look at the `JTextComponent` API, where the methods are defined, the two methods are defined together alphabetically. Its only when you look at the detail of method that they are separated.

Comment: I'm willing to admit that I was just stupid in this case, and I handled this topic poorly.  The only thing I stand by in this whole thread is that the pre-Java 8 docs were so much easier to understand than the Java 8 docs.  That is all.